# Wrong protocol or connection state for the requested transaction or request error on Windows Server 2012

Tags: vb6

We are migrate a old vb application from windows server 2000 to 2012, after the installation, the application give following errors when running:

> <40006> Wrong protocol or connection state for the requested
>   transaction or request (Winsock-->[WSUtils]frmClient.gfSendData
>   LN1-->[WSUtils]Client.SendData LN1-->[IIMMC]Client.msSendData
>   LN0-->[IIMMC]Client.LockSchedule LN0-->[IIMMC]frmMain.cmdLock_Click
>   LN0)

We dont have any source code for this application. How could I explore to find the reason caused the error? Thanks.

Comment: Winsock?  You're sure this is vb.net and not vb6?

Comment: @PaulAbbott, you are right, it is a VB6 application, I changed the hashtag to vb 6

Comment: Unfortunately, without seeing the source code, most answers will be shots in the dark. Take a look at [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?679915-Wrong-protocol-or-connection-state-for-the-requested-transaction-or-request) and [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?132636-Run-time-error-40006-Wrong-protocol-lt-How-this-error-occurs) to see if you can get a clue, but the resolutions there require you have access to the source.

Comment: And [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/183987)